# Kernel thread with the lowest priority

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, power-management

I'm implementing power management support for an embedded linux device. The requirement is to perform system suspend to memory when there's nothing left to run in the system and the next timer event is far enough. I'm intending to base on existing kernel enter_state() function 
Initially I planned to call my code from the cpu_idle() function (idle kernel thread) since it is run when there's nothing left to run in the system. But I encountered a problem that the enter_state() eventually calls schedule() function and then I get an error message: "bad: scheduling from the idle thread!"
So I concluded that I'll have to create my own kernel thread but with the lowest and static priority. My question is how that can be done? 
And another question: do you see any potential problems in such implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a kernel daemon thread with the scheduling policy set to SCHED_BATCH or SCHED_IDLE. These run only if there are no more process in run queue to schedule.
You can extend this to create the one such daemon thread on each cpu.
suspend device logic can be initiated here inside the thread.